# How to calculate BIC for K-Means to get best K

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I'm really new to K-Means clustering technique. I'd like to calculate BIC for K-Means to find best K (number of clusters). I looked around on the web to find a solution in python but there is no specific example except [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90769/using-bic-to-estimate-the-number-of-k-in-kmeans) which I'm not sure is correct. Any idea?

Comment: So, have you tried implementing the functions in Python?

Comment: Yes. here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195370/find-best-k-value-for-k-means-clustering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIC is basically a (justified) heuristic in the form of

```
BIC(theta|x, n) = -2 ln L(x|theta) + params(theta) lg n
```

where `x` are samples, `n` is number of samples, `theta` is your model, `params(theta)` is number of estimated parameters, and `L` is likelihood function associated with your model, thus you need **probabilistic model** which assigns probability (`ln L(x|theta) = ln PROD_{i=1}^n P(x|theta) = SUM_{i=1}^d ln P(x|theta)`). In fact, while it is easy to calculate params (as it is simply K*d, where K is K from K-means and d dimensionality of the space) you cannot really compute probability, as K-means does not provide you with probabilistic model directly.

On the other hand you can actually show (http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/3f3/1011/lect4.pdf) that there exists equivalent probabilistic approach, leading to the same cost function. Thus even though you are fitting non-probabilistic model in the first place, you can easily recover solution for actual probabilistic one after fitting k-means.

The correct python implementation is located for example here: https://github.com/mynameisfiber/pyxmeans/blob/master/pyxmeans/xmeans.py (their `_loglikelihood` function is `ln L(x|theta)` from the equation above).